# Can't pass parameters/sytem properties with gradlew command line

Tags: java, gradle

I try to pass parameters with gradlew command line, but can't.
I successfully pass the Optional parameter with XML file, but need have the possibility to pass with gradle CMD

Gradle task:

```golang
    task task1(type: Test) {
        useTestNG() {
            suites './src/test/resources/testng/task1.xml'
        }
    }
```

XML:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="test1">

    <test name="test1">
        <parameter name="ipAmount" value="20"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.traffic.Test1"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Code:

```java
    @Test(testName = "Name", description = "description")
    @Parameters({"ipAmount"})
    public void createTrafficTest(
            @Optional("1") Integer ipAmount
    ){
        final String IP_AMOUNT_PARAMETER = System.getProperty("ipAmount");

        System.out.println(ipAmount);//20
        System.out.println(IP_AMOUNT_PARAMETER);//null
    }
```

gradle CMD:

```sh
    gradlew clean task1 -DipAmount=2
```

```sh
    gradlew clean task1 -PipAmount=2
```

In both cases I get the same result: ipAmount=20, IP_AMOUNT_PARAMETER = null

## How to correctly pass parameters from the gradle cmd?

Comment: Can you try adding `systemProperties project.properties.subMap(["ipAmount"])` in your gradle task and try to pass it with `-PipAmount=2` in your cmd?

Comment: @Billatron this is the solution! You can post the answer - I grade up him!

Comment: Awesome, posted below! Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained also in the comment!

All you need to do is:

```
task task1(type: Test) {
systemProperties project.properties.subMap(["ipAmount"])
        useTestNG() {
            suites './src/test/resources/testng/task1.xml'
        }
    }
```

Then you can pass the property using `gradlew clean task1 -PipAmount=2`

Finally the `systemProperties` is a map so you can add more variables like `["ipAmount", "anotherParam", "moreParam"]`

Answer (score 1):

If your tests are being launched by the gradle `JavaExec` task then you can configure gradle to pass through its system properties like this:

```
// The run task added by the application plugin
// is also of type JavaExec.
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    // Assign all Java system properties from
    // the command line to the JavaExec task.
    systemProperties System.properties
}
```

See [the user guide](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2015/09/gradle-goodness-pass-java-system.html) for full details.